# Subsets of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, sumsets

There seems to be some combinatorial fact that every subset $A$ of  $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times n}$ of cardinality $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}+1$ containing $\vec{0}$ satisfies $(p-1)A=G$. ($p$ is a prime number.)
Is that true and known in the literature?
I would appreciate a reference or a proof.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $(p - 1)A$? Presumably it can't mean $\{(p-1)a | a \in A\}$. Do you mean $\{na | n \in [0, p - 1], a \in A\}$?

Comment: @user44191 iterative sumset: $(p-1)A := \{a_1+\dots+a_{p-1} : a_1,\dots,a_{p-1} \in A\}$.

Comment: Possibly related to https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.02564 also https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263914329_ADDITIVE_BASES_IN_ABELIAN_GROUPS

Comment: The condition $0\in A$ seems irrelevant: if the assertion is true for sets satisfying this condition, then it is true for all sets. Also, the bound $(p^n-1)/(p-1)+1$, if true, is best possible: consider the set $A$ of all $n$-tuples with the last nonzero coordinate equal to $1$.

Comment: Though i have not actually done the computation, it may be that the p=2 case can be established from the main result in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4902.pdf . More generally the compression method looks promising to attack the general case.

Comment: @TerryTao, the $p=2$ case is trivial: a subset $A \subseteq G$ of size $|G|$ certainly satisfies $A = G$.

Comment: Fair point. I said I didn’t do the computation :-).  But if there is a generalization of the main result of that paper to higher p then in principle this could resolve the question if the numbers work out.

Comment: In particular, the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316514000491 may be relevant. (I’m not at a location where I can do any actual computations, though.)

Comment: … in fact, it may be that by using the lemmas in that paper to reduce to the downset case, the result can then be finished off using the results in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96003032 (but again i have not been able to actually perform the required calculations)

Comment: Indeed the result follows easily from the Bollobas-Leader theory; I've posted it as an answer below.

Comment: In addition to Peter Taylor's comment, let me add that the claim is also trivial for $p=3$, since in this case $|A| > |G|/2$ which implies $|A+A|=|G|$ (as $A \cap (g-A)$ cannot be empty for any given $g \in G$). As observed by Seva, this does not use $0 \in A$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an alternative elementary way to prove this and see where the number $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}+1$ comes from.

**Lemma:** If $|A|\geq \frac{p^n-1}{p-1}+1$ then every point in $\mathbb F_p^n$ lies in a line that passes from two distinct points in $A$.

Proof: If this was false then there would be a point $P\notin A$ such that every line through $P$ contains at most one point of $A$. However the number of distinct lines passing through $P$ is $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$, the size of the corresponding projective space. This gives a contradiction, since it implies $|A|\le \frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$.

Returning to the statement in the OP, starting with an arbitrary point $P\in \mathbb F_p^n$ the lemma tells us that there are points $M,N\in A$ such that $-P$ lies in the line passing through $M$ and $N$. Now consider the line consisting of the points $kM+(p-1-k)N$, for $0\le k\le p-1$. This line contains $(p-1)M$ and $(p-1)N$, therefore it also contains $(p-1)(-P)=P$. This means that $P=kM+(p-1-k)N$ for some $k$, which is in $(p-1)A$, as desired.

Comment: Nice argument!  Basically you are able to leverage the $n=1$ case to handle the general case.

Comment: Very nice. Essentially makes the assertion obvious by exploiting the fact that the line through two points of a set lies in its $(p-1)$-fold sumset.

Answer (score 16):

From Theorem 10 of

*Bollobás, Béla; Leader, Imre*, [**Sums in the grid**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(96)00303-2), Discrete Math. 162, No. 1-3, 31-48 (1996). [ZBL0872.11007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0872.11007).

we know that if $A_1,\dots,A_k$ are subsets of $({\bf Z}/p)^{\times n}$ then
$$ |A_1+\dots+A_k| \geq |I_1+\dots+I_k|$$
where $I_j$ is the initial segment of $({\bf Z}/p)^{\times n}$ of the same cardinality as $A_j$.  (Strictly speaking, Theorem 10 only claims the $k=2$ case of this inequality, but the general case follows immediately by induction, together with the observation that the sum of two initial segments is again an initial segment; see also Corollary 7.)  In particular, in the current context one has
$$ |(p-1)A| \geq |(p-1)I|$$
where $I$ is the initial segment of length $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}+1$. This is the set of length $n$ strings base $p$ whose first non-zero coordinate is $1$, together with the string $(0,\dots,0)$ - basically the set already identified by Seva's comment.  (Indeed, I was led to the downset/compression literature by recognizing Seva's example as a downset.)  It is then a routine matter to check that $(p-1)I = ({\bf Z}/p)^{\times n}$, giving the claim.  (Indeed, for $1 \leq j \leq p-1$, one can check by induction that $jI$ consists of the length $n$ string whose first non-zero coordinate is at most $j$, plus the all-zero string.)